# 2-Component UIPickerView Overlapping

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView with two components, with one right justified and the other left justified. The outside of the pickerview is overlapping due to how the picker curves (see photo attached). How can I fix this without adding any unnecessary spacing? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Ouq.png)

Comment: use `pickerView.layer.borderWidth = 1` and `pickerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor.cgColor`to see what is going on, and post the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by splitting the picker view into two, making each curve the other direction. Thanks for the help!